# Querying an array field that contains hashes in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a problem in fetching the data from database. I have a array type column in mongodb database, in which i am saving hash type data in each array index. I have to get data on the basis of that hash match from the data base.

My data in database is saving like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("521603970ff5fa4b47000018"),
"message_text" : "#cricket #badminton #sachin #tendulkar #ibl #masterblaster #srt Cricketing world lights up IBL http://t.co/RWskRM2EQf via @msncricket",
"source" : "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/tweetbutton\" rel=\"nofollow\">Tweet Button</a>",
"status_id" : NumberLong("370521615638884352"),
"status_created_at" : "2013-08-22 17:53:31 +0530",
"user_id" : "31677680",
"screen_name" : "msncricket",
"name" : "MSN Cricket",
"followers_count" : 11515,
"friends_count" : 303,
"query" : [
    {
        "filterId" : "5215b40c0ff5fa111e000001",
        "subfilterId" : "60728003610375795",
        "type" : "keyword",
        "source" : "twitter",
        "monitoring_type" : false,
        "search_type" : false,
        "searchParameter" : "sachin",
        "geo" : "india",
        "language" : "en"
    }
]
}
```

The query column is the array type column.

During searching i make a hash again form matching it like follows

```
query = {"filterId"=>"5215b40c0ff5fa111e000001", "subfilterId"=>"60728003610375795",        "type"=>"keyword", "source"=>"twitter", "monitoring_type"=>false, "search_type" => false, "searchParameter"=>"sachin", "geo"=>"india", "language"=>"en"}
@result = Statuses.where({query: query})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find( { "query": { $elemMatch: { "filterId": "5215b40c0ff5fa111e000001", "subfilterId": "60728003610375795" } } } );
```

You are most probably looking for `elemMatch`. Check out the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/)

Comment: how can i run it in rails query active record

Comment: I don't use ruby. Sorry :( But now you can surely google for how to do elemMatch in what so ever ODM or wrapper you are using for mongo in ruby. :)

Comment: ummhhh... sorry, did you mean to say "its <not> working in mongodb console too"? Sorry my english is not good :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36080/discussion-between-sushant-gupta-and-sanyam-jain)